# How to change multiple variables of same data type in one go?

Tags: r

I am working in a data set where all the variables' data types are mixed up from their original data type.

str is below:

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   15 obs. of  13 variables:
 $ Invoice_No   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Invoice_Date : chr  "1-Apr-21" "1-Apr-21" "1-Apr-21" "3-Apr-21" ...
 $ Customer_Name: chr  "I" "F" "J" "C" ...
 $ Product      : chr  "AY201" "AY201" "GR70171" "SUB547" ...
 $ Qty          : int  150 50 25 200 200 100 25 2300 420 60 ...
 $ Price        : int  2350 2300 6950 390 1760 390 2450 260 267 390 ...
 $ Credit_Terms : int  45 10 1 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 ...
 $ Zone         : chr  "West" "West" "North" "North" ...
 $ Stock_in_date: chr  "2-Mar-21" "2-Mar-21" "8-Jan-21" "15-Jan-21" ...
 $ Purchase_Cost: num  1611 1611 4788 285 1611 ...
 $ Gross_Profit : num  100523 31084 26910 16651 15356 ...
 $ UOM          : chr  "KG" "KG" "KG" "KG" ...
 $ Invoice_Value: int  415950 135700 205025 92040 415360 46020 72275 706346 132325 27612 ...
```

Description of the data is given below.

Sales data with 15 row and 13 Columns:

1. Invoice_No: Invoice number (Data Type: Numeric)
2. Invoice_Date: Date of invoice (Data Type: Date)
3. Customer_Name: Name of the customer (Data Type: Factor)
4. Product: Product name (Data Type: Factor)
5. Qty: Quantity purchased (Data Type: Integer)
6. Price: Price of the product (Data Type: Integer)
7. Credit_Terms: Credit terms agreed by the customer 1/30/60/90 (Data Type: Factor)
8. Zone: Zone location of the customer NORTH/WEST/SOUTH/EAST (Data Type: Factor)
9. Stock_in_date: Purchase date of the product (Data Type: Date)
10. Purchase_Cost: Purchase price of the product (Data Type: Integer)
11. Gross_Profit: Profit (Data Type: Numeric)
12. UOM: Unit of Measurement of the product KG/LTR/NOS (Data Type: Factor)
13. Invoice_Value: Invoice value of the product (Data Type: Numeric)

As you can see the actual data set should have 3 num variables, 5 factor variables, 2 date variables, 3 int variables.

I am trying to change each type at one go. But it is not working.

```
df[c("Invoice_No","Gross_Profit","Invoice_Value")] <- as.numeric(pal_ex[c("Invoice_No","Gross_Profit","Invoice_Value")])
```

However this is working.

```
df["Invoice_No"] <- as.numeric(df["Invoice_No"])
```

How do I change the data type of multiple variables to same data type at one go?

I don't know what mistake I am doing. Please help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x <- c("Invoice_No","Gross_Profit","Invoice_Value")

df[x] <- lapply(df[x], \(i) as.numeric(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

A tidy solution is a such:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(c("Invoice_No","Gross_Profit","Invoice_Value"), as.numeric))
```